# Datatable - colspan dont showing correctly on Datatable

Tags: java, jquery, datatable

I have the next HTML Datatable

```
<div class="tabla-jquery">
    <table id="comparativa-data-table" class="dataTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th colspan="3">Fecha</th>
        </tr>
        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Prueba</td>
            <td>Izda</td>
            <td>Drha</td>
            <td>Axial</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And when I see the table, I get this error: Cannot read property 'fnSetData' of undefined

But when I change the HTML and put this:

```
<div class="tabla-jquery">
    <table id="comparativa-data-table" class="dataTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Fecha</th><th>Fecha</th><th>Fecha</th>
        </tr>
        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Prueba</td>
            <td>Izda</td>
            <td>Drha</td>
            <td>Axial</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

It works "fine"(I only want a Fecha header instead of 3):

[image]

Anyone knows why occur this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you using jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) here? Or is this just a plain HTML table?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<div class="tabla-jquery">
<table id="comparativa-data-table" class="dataTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Titulo</th>
        <th colspan="3">Fecha</th>
        <th style="display:none;">Fecha</th>
        <th style="display:none;">Fecha</th>
    </tr>
    
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Prueba</td>
        <td>Izda</td>
        <td>Drha</td>
        <td>Axial</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```